# How to get the name of the selected items from the ListView

Tags: c#, microsoft-metro, listviewitem

I have a ListView in the itemDetailPage and I would like to share the selected item via e-mail. For which, I need to get the selected item from that listview.

What I tried is

```
if(listview1.SelectedItems.Count==1)
{
   var item = listview1.SelectedItem
}
```

But I dont get the name, I get only the place it is taken from. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Use `Count` instead of `count`. C# is case sensitive.

```
if(listview1.SelectedItems.Count == 1)
{
   var item = listview1.SelectedItems[0].ToString();
}
```

Comment: Thanks! But I dont ahve the Text property. I ahve only Equals, getType and toString!

Comment: @dmurali Use `ToString()` then `;)`

Comment: Thanx Soner Gönül, but I still dont get to share the name of the item. I only get to share "Project.DataModel.Node" as output.

Comment: And also, my project if of single-selection enabled! So will it be getSelectedItem and not Items?

Answer (score 1):

Try this. You need to cast `SelectedItem` with your model class.

```
if (listview1.SelectedItems.Count==1)
{
   var item = listview1.SelectedItems[0] as Node
}
```

Comment: It works..!! Thanx Xyroid and Soner for your help..! The correct version is  `var item1 = itemListView.SelectedItems[0] as Node;
             e.Request.Data.SetText("Hello, read something interesting about '" + item1.Text)`